# asp.net c# __doPostBack button in UpdatePanel is working on second click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Situation:
I'm using multiview in my aspx.
in 2 views I have UpdatePanels and literals inside. my UpdatePanels are triggered by a timer (same timer). by c# I'm creating same postback button into these literals.
in my view1 I have 1 updatepanel and when I click the button it should activate view2. in view2 I have 2 different updatepanels. in first one I have this same button.
in this postback button I'm doing something and activating view2. My problem is the button in view1 is working on only second click. in view2, same button is working on first click. from my point of view, the only difference is view. all other details are perfectly same.
if I remove updatepanel from view1, button is working properly. so I'm assuming that problem is about UpdatePanel. in view2, same button is in updatepanel and it works properly. so I'm assuming that problem is view.

c# my button creation:

```
<td><input type='image' src='images/zoom1.png' id='btn' value='Match' onclick='javascript:__doPostBack(\"Match1\",\"" + dr1.GetValue(0).ToString() + "\");' ></td>
```

my button action:

```
private void Match1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
 job1
 job2
 job3
 MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2;            
}
```

my page_load:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null && Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "Match1")
    {
        Match1_Click(null, null);
    }
}
```

my updatepanels are like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
       <div>
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
      </div>
   </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick"/>
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I try to do step over and move one by one with f10, I realized something strange. when I click the button at first, it triggers the action, I press f10 and it moves 1 line down then 4 lines up, 5 line down 3 lines up etc... and it doesn't end properly. so action is not ending as expected. when I click the button second time, I can move with  f10 properly and everything works as expected.

Comment: which button does the submit? `Match1_Click`?

Comment: yes. submit button is: onclick='javascript:__doPostBack(\"Match1\",\"" + dr1.GetValue(0).ToString() + "\"); ...... and Match1_Click is the action.

Comment: Afair, this is somehow related to validators or custom validators. Are there any on your page?

Comment: @ADOConnection in my aspx page I have only "RequiredFieldValidator" and it is for user login.